# how to push side bar menu to another viewController in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I use in my application, the side bar menu like in facebook, so I have different cells in this menu, what I want is to when click on a cell push me to another view controller. I am using this code. Please give me any idea

Viewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)onBurger:(id)sender 

{

 NSArray *images = @[

[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"globe"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"globe"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"globe"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"],

[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"],

];

NSArray *colors = @[

[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.f green:159/255.f blue:254/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.f green:137/255.f blue:167/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:126/255.f green:242/255.f blue:195/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:119/255.f green:152/255.f blue:255/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.f green:159/255.f blue:254/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.f green:137/255.f blue:167/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:126/255.f green:242/255.f blue:195/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:119/255.f green:152/255.f blue:255/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.f green:159/255.f blue:254/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.f green:137/255.f blue:167/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:126/255.f green:242/255.f blue:195/255.f alpha:1],

[UIColor colorWithRed:119/255.f green:152/255.f blue:255/255.f alpha:1],
                        ];

    RNFrostedSidebar *callout = [[RNFrostedSidebar alloc] initWithImages:images selectedIndices:self.optionIndices borderColors:colors];

//    RNFrostedSidebar *callout = [[RNFrostedSidebar alloc] initWithImages:images];

callout.delegate = self;

//    callout.showFromRight = YES;

[callout show];

}

#pragma mark - RNFrostedSidebarDelegate

- (void)sidebar:(RNFrostedSidebar *)sidebar didTapItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{

 NSLog(@"Tapped item at index %i",index);

if (index == 3) 

{

[sidebar dismiss];

}

else if(index==2)

{

[sidebar dismiss];

 }


else if(index==1)

{

[sidebar dismiss];

}

 else if(index==0)

{

[sidebar dismiss];

}

}

- (void)sidebar:(RNFrostedSidebar *)sidebar didEnable:(BOOL)itemEnabled itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 

{

if (itemEnabled) 

{

[self.optionIndices addIndex:index];

 }

else 

{

[self.optionIndices removeIndex:index];

}

}
```

Comment: what happens while you push any viewController with navigation like we does in normal conditions? if not yet tried then try it and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, I have used this and was working fine.
[JASidePanels is a UIViewController container designed for presenting a center panel with revealable side panels - one to the left and one to the right. The main inspiration for this project is the menuing system in Path 2.0 and Facebook's iOS apps.](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)